# No puedo userServer-side DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatable, angular-datatables

Estoy intentanto utilizar server-side pero al momento de colocarlo me despliega todos los datos sin hacerme ninguna paginacin. les comparto el como lo estoy  utilizando.

```js
    var genealogytable = $('#arbol').DataTable({
      "bProcessing": true,
      "bServerSide": true,
      destroy: true,
      ajax: { 
        url: "arbol",
        type: "get", 
        datatype: "json", 
        data: {
            _token:$('#_token').val(),
          idsponsor: idsponsor,
          period: period,
          typee: typee,
        },
      },
      columns: [  
        {data: 'mobile_number'},//7
        {data: 'alternative_number'},//8
        {data: 'country'},//9
        {data: 'State_ID'},//10
        {data: 'PinRank'},//11
        {data: 'PayRank'},//12
        {data: 'InactiveMonths'},//13
        {data: 'RenewalDate', type:"text"},//14
        {data: 'SignupDate', type:"date"},//15
      ],
```

Comment: Hola deberías revisar la respuesta del request, es decir la respuesta del GET  /arbol, ya que Datatable necesita que la respuesta sea un objeto el cual contenga los siguientes atributos `recordsTotal`  cantidad de registros en total,  `recordsFiltered` que es la cantidad de registros que machean con el filtro que hayas mandado, si es que mandaste alguno, en tal caso es el mismo valor que `recordsTotal` y por ultimo el valor `data` que es un Array; te mando el link de la documentación que a mi me sirvió muchisimo [Datatable ServerSide](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side)

Comment: Desconozco la opción `bServerSide`, pero quiero suponer que trabaja igual que [serverSide](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side) donde la paginación es controlada desde el servidor. Si vas a devolver todos los resultados en una sola petición, pon esa propiedad en `false`, para que paginación y otras funcionalidades se hagan en el navegador.